# MySQL: why still 'using filesort' when indexes are used?

Tags: mysql, filesort

mysql-5.6.24-win32.1432006610

I have two tables for users' messages.

`TMessageBody (id, body)` stores body of messages.

`TMessage     (id, uid, folderId, msgBodyId,  subject)` 
stores messages of users in folders, such as Inbox, Outbox.

---

**Create Table SQL**:

```
create table TMessageBody (
    id          int unsigned    not null    primary key auto_increment,
    body        text            not null
);


create table TMessage (
    id          int unsigned    not null    primary key auto_increment,
    uid         int unsigned    not null,
    folderId    int unsigned    not null,
    msgBodyId   int unsigned    not null,
    subject     varchar(256)    not null
);
```

---

**Some test data**:

```
insert into TMessageBody 
    (body) values 
    ('Here is body 1')
    ,('Here is body 2')
    ,('Here is body 3')
    ,('Here is body 4')
    ,('Here is body 5')
    ,('Here is body 6')
    ,('Here is body 7')
    ,('Here is body 8')
    ,('Here is body 9')
    ;

insert into TMessage
    (uid, folderId, msgBodyId, subject) values
    (1, 999, 1, 'Hello jack')
    , (1, 999, 2, 'Jack, how are you')
    , (1, 888, 3, 'Good morning jack')
    , (2, 888, 4, 'I love you, rose')
    , (2, 999, 5, 'I love you, rose')
    , (3, 888, 6, 'Peter, please call back')
    , (3, 999, 7, 'What are you doing, Peter')
    , (3, 999, 8, 'Happy birthday, perter')
    , (4, 999, 9, 'Let me know if you are ready')
    ;
```

---

**Indexes**:

```
create index Idx_MsgBodyId      on TMessage(msgBodyId);
create index Idx_Uid_FolderId   on TMessage(uid, folderId);
```

---

**1.FileSort shows when `folderId` is not in the WHERE clause**

The below query gets all messages including message body by a given user id :

```
SET @uid=3;
SET @folderId=999;

EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM        TMessage
INNER JOIN  TMessageBody 
ON          TMessage.msgBodyId=TMessageBody.id
WHERE       TMessage.uid=@uid
                #AND TMessage.folderId=@folderId
ORDER BY    TMessage.id DESC
;
```

The EXPLAIN result is:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
-> SELECT *
->  FROM            TMessage
->  INNER JOIN      TMessageBody
->  ON              TMessage.msgBodyId=TMessageBody.id
->  WHERE           TMessage.uid=@uid
->                      #AND TMessage.folderId=@folderId
->  ORDER BY        TMessage.id DESC
->  ;
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                  | key              | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TMessage     | ref    | Idx_MsgBodyId,Idx_Uid_FolderId | Idx_Uid_FolderId | 4       | const                   |    3 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TMessageBody | eq_ref | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY          | 4       | test.TMessage.msgBodyId |    1 | NULL                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**2.FileSort disappears when `folderId` is in the WHERE clause**

The query is as same as the above one except the WHERE clause :

```
SET @uid=3;
SET @folderId=999;

EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM        TMessage
INNER JOIN  TMessageBody 
ON          TMessage.msgBodyId=TMessageBody.id
WHERE       TMessage.uid=@uid
            　　AND TMessage.folderId=@folderId
ORDER BY    TMessage.id DESC
;
```

The EXPLAIN result is:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
-> SELECT *
->  FROM            TMessage
->  INNER JOIN      TMessageBody
->  ON              TMessage.msgBodyId=TMessageBody.id
->  WHERE           TMessage.uid=@uid
->                            AND TMessage.folderId=@folderId
->  ORDER BY        TMessage.id DESC
->  ;
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                  | key              | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TMessage     | ref    | Idx_MsgBodyId,Idx_Uid_FolderId | Idx_Uid_FolderId | 8       | const,const             |    2 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TMessageBody | eq_ref | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY          | 4       | test.TMessage.msgBodyId |    1 | NULL        |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**Question**:

The difference between the two queries is whether the `folderId` column is in the `WHERE` clause. According the EXPLAIN result, both queries use the `Idx_Uid_FolderId` index. I want to know why the one shows FileSort but the other does not.

---

**Update**

Tried to use `ORDER BY TMessage.folderId, TMessage.id DESC` in the first query. But `Using filesort` still exists in the EXPLAIN result.

```
mysql> EXPLAIN
-> SELECT *
->  FROM        TMessage
->  INNER JOIN  TMessageBody
->  ON          TMessage.msgBodyId=TMessageBody.id
->  WHERE       TMessage.uid=@uid
->                   #AND TMessage.folderId=@folderId
->  ORDER BY    TMessage.folderId, TMessage.id DESC
->  ;
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys                  | key              | key_len | ref                     | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TMessage     | ref    | Idx_MsgBodyId,Idx_Uid_FolderId | Idx_Uid_FolderId | 4       | const                   |    3 | Using where; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TMessageBody | eq_ref | PRIMARY                        | PRIMARY          | 4       | test.TMessage.msgBodyId |    1 | NULL                        |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+--------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------+------+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of an index as a concatenated value.

In this case, your index is

```
uid | folderId | id
```

id is last because it is a reference in your secondary index to your primary key.

In the first scenario, you filter by uid and then sort by id. The problem is that MySQL cannot assume that id is ordered due, since the index is actually ordered by folderId before being filtered by id.

ex:

```
uid | folderId | id
  1 |        1 |  1
  1 |        2 |  2
  2 |        1 |  3
```

Therefore this index cannot be used for sorting, since the sorting of the index is different than the order by clause.

Now, my question would be: Why are you trying to avoid the filesort? Unless you are hitting performance problems, using filesort is perfectly fine. Despite the name, the sorting is done in memory, unless specified otherwise (using temporary).

Comment: I've tried `ORDER BY TMessage.folderId, TMessage.id DESC` in the first query, `Using filesort` still exists. As you said, it is acceptable in most cases, but I still wonder why in this case.

Comment: @Zach oh, I'll remove that bit from my answer then